# Construct ImmutableSortedSet without warnings

Tags: java, guava, construction

I want construct `ImmutableSortedSet`. I wrote code smt like:

```
Set<String> obj = new HashSet<String>();
Comparator<String> myComparator = new Comparator<String>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return 0;
    }           
};
Set<String> ordered = ImmutableSortedSet.copyOf(obj)
    .orderedBy(myComparator).build();
```

but it generates warning:

> The static method
>   orderedBy(Comparator) from the
>   type ImmutableSortedSet should
>   be accessed in a static way

How can I remove this warning without `@SuppressWarnings("static-access")`? Thanks.

Comment: Yikes!  Does anyone know, do both javac and eclipse give that warning?  (Please say yes.)

Comment: @Kevin Bourrillion, eclipse do. but my javac doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's giving you that warning because `orderedBy` is a static method and you're calling it on an instance of `ImmutableSortedSet`. This often means you think you're doing one thing when really you're doing something else, and that's the case here.

The result is that this code isn't going to do what you think it does... it's going to throw away the `ImmutableSortedSet` created by `copyOf(obj)` (it's only being used to access the static method `orderedBy`, which could be used directly) and return an empty set, as if you had just called `ImmutableSortedSet.orderedBy(myComparator).build()`.

Here's what you want to do (as R. Bemrose said):

```
ImmutableSortedSet<String> ordered = ImmutableSortedSet.copyOf(myComparator, obj);
```

For posterity, here's what I hastily posted initially (which has the same result):

```
ImmutableSortedSet<String> ordered = ImmutableSortedSet.orderedBy(myComparator)
    .addAll(obj).build();
```

Answer (score 3):

After looking at the Guava `ImmutableSortedSet` docs, it appears that you actually want one of the other overloads to `copyOf`.

Specifically, you want the [`copyOf(Comparator, Collection)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSortedSet.html#copyOf%28java.util.Comparator,%20java.util.Collection%29) overload:

```
Set<String> ordered = ImmutableSortedSet.copyOf(myComparator, obj);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll do as you say. But I promise to assept @ColinD's answer(

Comment: You're right, this method is the right one to use for what the author wants to do, though the end result is the same.